# Different color for the active item in the menu bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the color of the first item in this menu (that way the user knows is the active item), any help?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="current">jkfasdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">jkffasdf fjaskdfasfs jajklfd fjklasdfas</a></li>
</ul>

ul{
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  float: left; #esto permite que se adapte el ancho del ul al contenido..
  # quizas por ello no se pueda centrar si se quiere :)
}

li {
  padding: 10px; display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li:first-child {border-left: none;}

li.current {
   background: yellow;
}

a {

}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3NCq/46/

Comment: Do you want to apply yellow `background` on first `li` element or first `a` element in `li`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space: `li .current {`. Without the space it is trying to apply it to an `li` item with a class of `current`, where you want it applied to a child of `li` with the class of `current`.

Comment: @Amberlamps sorry but not for me, there is red color around the yellow area http://jsfiddle.net/y3NCq/52/

Comment: @tirengarfio That's because of other styling of the element and its surroundings. You can tweak the rest of the styling to your desire, but this is how to target the element. The red is the background colour of your unordered list, the parent.

Comment: @tirengarfio **li.current** is said .current class with LI & **li .content** is said .current class within LI.

Comment: @tirengarfio: You have to style the `li` also to get an all yellow item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
li a.current {
    background: yellow;
}
```